# CfSetInSyncState fails with ERROR_NOT_A_CLOUD_FILE after a file update

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the Cloud Mirror [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/cloudmirror-sample/) and I am having problems to set a file sync state after I edit a .txt file with WordPad app. When I try to set the file sync state to in sync state (CF_IN_SYNC_STATE_IN_SYNC) I am getting the error ERROR_NOT_A_CLOUD_FILE. But when I use the Notepad app I can change the file sync state successfully without errors. If anyone has some suggestions for this issue and can share it with me I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests and taking account the [Rita Han - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6601582/rita-han-msft) answer I couldn't set the file reparse point, like I posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943428/deviceiocontrol-fails-with-error-395-to-set-a-reparse-point?noredirect=1#comment113241161_63943428). But I can use the [CfSetInSyncState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetinsyncstate) without errors using the [CfConvertToPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfconverttoplaceholder) function to convert the file to a placeholder again, because after a txt file modification with some apps like WordPad the file isn't a placeholder anymore. And to check if the file is a placeholder I used the [CfGetPlaceholderStateFromFindData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfgetplaceholderstatefromfinddata) function. The code was the next:

**1- Get placeholder state**

```
    CF_PLACEHOLDER_STATE result = CF_PLACEHOLDER_STATE::CF_PLACEHOLDER_STATE_INVALID;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    HANDLE hFileHandle = FindFirstFileEx(
        filePath.data(), // wstring with the file path
        FindExInfoStandard,
        &findData,
        FindExSearchNameMatch,
        NULL,
        FIND_FIRST_EX_ON_DISK_ENTRIES_ONLY);

    if (hFileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        result = CfGetPlaceholderStateFromFindData(&findData); // Placeholder state
    }
```

**2- Convert the file to a placeholder again**

```
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(
        filePath.data(), // wstring with the file path
        WRITE_DAC,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT,
        NULL);

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //Invalid handle
    }

    HRESULT hr = CfOpenFileWithOplock(filePath.c_str(), CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAGS::CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE, &fileHandle);

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        LPCVOID fileIdentity = filePath.data();
        DWORD fileIdentityLength = (USHORT)(wcslen(filePath.data()) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
        CF_CONVERT_FLAGS convertFlags = CF_CONVERT_FLAGS::CF_CONVERT_FLAG_MARK_IN_SYNC;
        USN* convertUsn = nullptr;
        LPOVERLAPPED overlapped = NULL;

        hr = CfConvertToPlaceholder(fileHandle, fileIdentity, fileIdentityLength, convertFlags, convertUsn, overlapped);

        if (hr == S_OK)
        {
            // The placeholder was converted successfully
        }
```

**3- Change the file state**

```
    HANDLE fileHandle;
    // filePath is a wstring with the file path
    HRESULT hr = CfOpenFileWithOplock(filePath.c_str(), CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAGS::CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_WRITE_ACCESS, &fileHandle);

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        hr = CfSetInSyncState(fileHandle, CF_IN_SYNC_STATE::CF_IN_SYNC_STATE_IN_SYNC, CF_SET_IN_SYNC_FLAGS::CF_SET_IN_SYNC_FLAG_NONE, NULL);

        if (hr == S_OK)
        {
            // The file state was changed successfully
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue.

After comparing the **file attributes** between edited by Notepad app or WordPad app, I discover that [Attribute letter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-cloud-tiering#how-can-i-tell-whether-a-file-has-been-tiered) "L" is missed after edited by WordPad and there is only attribute letter "A".

[image]

**The file only has an attribute "A" consider as a common file instead of a cloud file.** This describe the error you received: `ERROR_NOT_A_CLOUD_FILE`    (The file is not a cloud file).

You can check file attributes like this:

[image]

So use Notepad instead of Wordpad to edit TXT file. Or you can store the a reparse point before edition and set it back after edition. (This part not tested.)

More reference: "[Reparse Point Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-point-operations)".

Comment: Hello Rita, I have already noticed that the file attributes after a file modification with WordPad were 32 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) instead of 1056 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) like a file modification with Notepad. And I tried to change the file attributes with the SetFileAttributes method but recently I could see that it is not possible. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Glad to help! You can accept the answer that will help other are searching on similar issue.

Comment: Hi @Rita, currently I am working in this solution because I am having some issues, when I finish the development and everything works I will accept your answer.

Comment: Hello @Rita yesterday I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943428/deviceiocontrol-fails-with-error-395-to-set-a-reparse-point) related with my currently issue.